# What are the consequences of unregistering MSOXMLMF.DLL

Tags: windows, debugging, ms-office, windbg

Got a weird crash (access violation) where an address is “called” in MSOXMLMF while, accoring to windbg, the library is not (more) loaded on the moment of the “call”.

Note: the "call" is a return to a once legal return address in MSOXMLMF  (no symbol information of this office 2010 DLL downloadable).

In order to check what happens when MSOXMLMF can’t be the issue, we want to unregister this DLL. What might be the consequences of this action?

Comment: maybe helps `regsvr32.exe /u [path]\msoxmlmf.dll` http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841532 for ofiice 2003

Comment: Saw that one, no more recognition of office documents, could be bad, but can give it a try.